# How to remove Splash Screen in the Intel XDK

Tags: html, css, intel, intel-xdk

How to remove Splash Screen in the Intel XDK, 
Someone posted code in another question
but i don't understand how to do this code where to add and anything else.
Please help...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove splash screen in **Intel XDK emulator**, open the "Device and Network Settings" section on the right side panel in emulator tab, there is an option to uncheck "simulate splash screen".

To remove splash screen in the app build, you have add this line:

```
intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
```

Here is example app code that will hide splash screen as soon as device is ready:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XDK</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />

    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script>               
        function onDeviceReady(){
            intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();   
        }        
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);        
    </script>
    <style>
        body {font-family:arial;background-color:white}
    </style>    
</head>
<body> 
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```